# Black screen after booting to Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04

I have a dual-boot system with Windows 10 on an internal SSD and Ubuntu running on an external one.

I've set up the Ubuntu drive the day before yesterday. Everything worked fine, I switched back and forth between the two systems, and everything went as I expected: By default, it boots to  Win 10, and if I wanted to get to Ubuntu, I had to restart and use the F12 boot menu.

Today I had to disconnect the external SSD (Ubuntu) while in Windows. - *somehow I feel this is what caused the issue, but no idea why or how* - I reconnected it to the same port a few hours later, and now I can't boot into Ubuntu:

I can select it without any problem from the quick boot menu, but it leads to a blank / black screen, and the only thing I can do is shutting off the machine by holding down the power button for a few seconds. I've tried restarting many times, no luck.

In Windows, I can't see the external drive in This PC, however, it appears in the boot menu and in the device manager aswell. Even tried to update it's driver, but it says it's up to date. I can see both drives in Disk Management too, but can't seem to do anything with the Ubuntu one... all options upon right-click are greyed out. - I guess because of the different file system.

As I said, everything worked fine for 2 days, I switched between the two OS-es, turned off the PC many times, but managed to boot up Ubuntu on every occasion. All this trouble started today, after dis- and reconnecting the drive housing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a new dual-boot configuration, you may have to check this...

**Windows**

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

Then try and boot Ubuntu.

**Ubuntu**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Installed Nvidia Geforce 1650 driver version 470 and it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Thanks. I followed through your suggestion. The Windows section was easy-peasy. The Ubuntu segment failed at the fsck part. It said: Cannot continue fsck because the drive is in use. I repeated the command many times, but to no avail. Also I made the observation that my screen won't just simply go black, but it turns off.

Comment: @Miska You forgot the first step... boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Comment: @heynema No, I started with that. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to get to a terminal.

Comment: @Miska If you have a swap partition on the drive, do a `sudo swapoff /dev/sdXX`, replacing the XX with the appropriate swap partition number. You can also do this using `gparted`.

Comment: Tried it, no luck. I reinstalled Ubuntu, but the issue came back after a few days of normal use.

Comment: @Miska In Windows, did you install a driver that allows you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions? Did the `fsck` work? What video card, and what version driver? How big is external drive? Install on GPT or MBR partition table?

Comment: @heynemma Yes, 'fsck' worked after applying the swapoff command. It returned no errors, but couldn't solve my original problem with the black screen. I have a Geforce 1650. Never checked the drivers, always relied on the software updater. This time, because I've read that it might be a display-driver related problem, I opted for the Nvidia proprietary (tested) driver: v 470. We'll see in a few days if the issue will be coming back.

Comment: @Miska You didn't answer my other questions from my last comment. Do you run with wayland or X11/xorg?

Comment: it's on Xorg. The drive is 128 GB / MBR.

Comment: @Miska Is it working now with Nvidia 470?

Comment: Seems so. It still works / 3 days from installation. Thanks for your help.